# How to allow user to login with both username and email in php?

Tags: php

i am currently having problem allowing user to login with both username or email and entered and matching it with the database, here is my code:

```
<?php
//Login Script
if (isset($_POST["user_login"]) && isset($_POST["password_login"])) {
    $user_login = $_POST["user_login"]; 
    $password_login = $_POST["password_login"];
    $md5password_login = md5($password_login);
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM users2 WHERE username='$user_login' AND password='$md5password_login' LIMIT 1"); // query the person

    //Check for their existance
    $userCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql); //Count the number of rows returned

    if ($userCount == 1) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
             $rahul = $row["id"];
        }

        $_SESSION["id"] = $rahul;
        $_SESSION["user_login"] = $user_login;
        $_SESSION["password_login"] = $password_login;
       exit("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=./home.php\">");
    } else {
        echo 'That information is incorrect, try again';
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

i don't know what to add in the mysqli_query to allow user to login from both the username and email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple change your query like this

```
 $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM users2 WHERE (username='$user_login' OR `email`='$user_login') AND password='$md5password_login' LIMIT 1"); // query the person
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT id FROM users2 WHERE ( username='$user_login' OR email='$user_login') AND password='$md5password_login' LIMIT 1"
```

Here `$user_login` can be either username or email.

For the security you must escape the inputs like

```
$user_login = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["user_login"]);
$password_login =  mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["password_login"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your sql query like this:

```
    "SELECT id FROM users2 WHERE (username='$user_login' OR email='$user_login') AND password='$md5password_login' LIMIT 1"
```

the query will use either username or email as your primary login key while password is mandatory field.